# Photoshop CC: Drag moves top layer not panel selected layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Just got a new computer running windows 10 at work, was previously on windows 7. The version of Photoshop CC for windows 10 does something strange that previous Photoshop versions never did.

When I click & drag an item with the move tool, it grabs and moves whatever is highest in the layers panel that I click on in the canvas. Previously, it would move whatever was highlighted in the layers panel. Any idea how to change it back? Seems like a new "feature" but is driving me crazy.

Example- I have a group of elements I want to drag to the bottom of the canvas, but when I click and drag it only moves the object I click on.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is because you most likely have `auto-select` checked.

[image: autoselect checbox is checked]

As the name implies the `auto-select` feature will auto-select either the closest group or layer underneath your cursor (you can set the specificity in the dropdown next to the checkbox). Unchecking the option will make the move tool interact with whatever layer you have selected.

Comment: You're the best! I knew it was a setting just couldnt find it

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been annoyed by this for a few months since upgrading